# Expresso Store Togging between Ex Tax and Inc Tax

Tags: expresso-store, devdemon, expresso

All products on my store are entered excluding VAT/TAX. All Items are Taxable at 20%.

We're currently showing the prices on the site excluding VAT and VAT is added at the checkout. However, the site has been reported to the ASA (Advertising Standards Authority) and they have deemed that we need to show all prices Ex. and Inc. VAT.

The client has asked for a toggle that the user can select - however, I'm have trouble even simply showing the prices Including VAT... the `{price_inc_tax}` doesn't appear to work even though I've set the TAX rule to apply to all products in all areas.

Anyone ever accomplished showing both Ex. and Inc. VAT/TAX on the page?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at this add-on? https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/add-vat